# ElasticSearch 6 High Level Rest Client preparePutMapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to transition from ElasticSearch 2 to either 5 or 6.  I think that I want to jump straight to 6.1.1 and use the RestHighLevelClient, since it is closer to the existing transport client that I am using than the low level rest client.

However, I am running across a problem  As part of my integration tests, I'm creating an index and inserting particular data, so I know that my queries are correct.  I can't seem to do that in the High Level client.  In particular, I want to be able to call:

```
  RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port)))
  client.indices()
        .preparePutMapping(databaseName)
        .setType(tableName).etc....
```

However, client.indices() returns an org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient (from org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.1.1) which does not have a preparePutMapping().  I need a org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesAdminClient (from org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.1.1).  I can't figure out how to get that, from either RestHighLevelClient or RestClient.

Am I out of luck?   Is this just transition pains that it has not been implemented yet?  Or something more permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.1/java-admin-indices.html):

```
client.admin().indices()
      .preparePutMapping(databaseName)   
      .setType(tableName)
      ...
```

Looks like all you need is an additional `.admin()`.

Comment: As far as I know, the solution provided is for the Java API client, and the original question is for High level REST API client (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm facing the very same problem, I need to migrate a `preparePutMapping` from Java API client to Hight Level REST API client. Please, if anyone know what could be the best approach for that, I really appreciate yor help (and I'm sure that C Dorman too). Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, that was for the Transport client. I'm afraid you'll have to wait for 6.4 to have this feature: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/30400